# Functions that operate on symbolic matrices?

Tags: pattern-matching, linear-algebra, symbolic

I'd like to write functions that operate on symbolic matrices, and do nothing when fed anything else.

```
ClearAll[M, x, n, d, g, f];
$Assumptions = {M \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}]}
TensorDimensions[M.M]  
(* yields {2,2} *)
f[M_ ] := TensorDimensions[M.M] 
f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]  
(* yields {2,2} *)
f[M]                 
(* yields {2,2} *)
f[x]  
(* yields TensorDimensions::scdot: Expression x.x contains the scalar subexpression x. >>   TensorDimensions[x.x] ...  I would like to get f[x]*)
f[3.]
(* yields TensorDimensions::scdot: Expression x.x contains the scalar subexpression 3' >>   TensorDimensions[3.3]...  I would like to get f[3.]*)
```

How do I go about that? Restricting f as in

```
f[M_  /; M \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}]] := TensorDimensions[M.M];
```

does not work.  This function returns {2,2} for the numerically defined matrix, but f[M] for the symbolically defined one.

Of course, the above is meaningless as the function definition implies its output {2,2}. So for this to be useful it should work on Matrices[{d,d}] for variable d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Element.html) per default doesn't seem to [use assertions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingAssumptions.html). You can make it use assertions when evaluating whether M is an element of `Matrices[{2,2}]` by using `Refine`

```
 f[M_ /; Refine[M \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}]]] := TensorDimensions[M.M]
```

Comment: Thanks -- that gets me partially there. How would I make the function operate on matrices of variable dimensions as in f[M_ /; Refine[M \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}]]] := TensorDimensions[M.M]

Comment: @Eric Perhaps checking to see if `TensorRank` evaluates does the trick for you? eg. `Head@TensorRank[b] =!= TensorRank`